# Fourier transform of sound wave

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

I am a high school student doing a project in Fourier transform. I was planning to learn Fourier transform and manually apply the calculations to a section of a song and see what I get. However, I need to learn Fourier transform on my own and most tutorials I found are on expanding square wave etc, which isn't very helpful for my plan (now seems too ambitious) as I will be dealing with aperiodic waves.

Moreover, I was seeing all those different types of Fourier transform (DFT, CFT, STFT....)
I am a little lost as to how to apply the formulas and what type of Fourier transform should I learn to analyse the sound wave of a song...
Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: You probably want a spectrogram rather than just a fourier transform. It's a little more complicated, but it produces something to look at that you could make sense of. Many software packages can do this. So, basically, as a start, find software that you think you can use that can produce a spectrogram. For example, [Audacity can do this](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/spectrogram_view.html), or something like Python and [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/specgram_demo.html).

Comment: Don't start with something complicated like real audio data. Can you Fourier transform a single sine wave? What about a Gaussian? Slowly build up on some examples that can be done analytcally before you try to handle something noisy.